# I want to retrieve data stored in firebase which is stored as an array. then I need to get the array from firebase and store it in a list in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, firebase, dart

**This is the sample of my database **
[sample of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcEhv.png)

I need to fetch those array and stored into a list

**This is the model class that i created  for those data**

```
> class ContainerItems {   String Title, time, daytime, iconName;
> 
>   ContainerItems({required this.Title,
>     required this.iconName,
>     required this.time,
>     required this.daytime}); }
```

and please show me how to access each individual items. in the list

**please help**

Comment: you're referring to iconName as 'image' in your database, right ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy- its just the image path that stored on my device.

Answer (score 0):

well i got the answer..... hope this help others also.

Here todaysmeal is a refactored widget.

```
 class messDiary extends StatefulWidget {   messDiary({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {}
    
      // late String whatIsToday = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());
    
      @override   State<messDiary> createState() => _messDiaryState(); }
    
    class _messDiaryState extends State<messDiary> {   int activeIndex = 0;   final carouselController = CarouselController();   String valueChoose = 'Select a day';   var itemName;
    
      final DocumentReference _collectData =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messdiary').doc('days');
    
      late Stream<DocumentSnapshot> _streamCollect;
    
      @override   void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _streamCollect = _collectData.snapshots();   }
    
      @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: const bottomNavigation(),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  headings(headingText: "Today's meals"),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                      stream: _streamCollect,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        final snaps = snapshot.data!;
                        final sundayMeals = snaps["sunday"]
                            .map((e) => todaysMeal(
                                itemName: e['title'],
                                itemImage: e['image'],
                                time: e['time'],
                                dayTime: e['daytime']))
                            .toList();
                        final List<Widget> mealsData = [...sundayMeals];
                        return CarouselSlider(
                          options: CarouselOptions(
                            height: height * 0.38,
                            aspectRatio: 2.0,
                            autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
                            pauseAutoPlayTouch: true,
                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                            initialPage: 2,
                            autoPlay: true,
                            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                              setState(() {
                                activeIndex = index;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          items: mealsData,
                        );
                      }),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                    onDotClicked: animateToSlide,
                    effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                        dotWidth: 14,
                        dotHeight: 14,
                        activeDotColor: Color(0xFF6A7086),
                        dotColor: Color(0xFF2B2E3F)),
                    activeIndex: activeIndex,
                    count: 4,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    color: Color(0xFF6A6C70),
                    indent: 20,
                    endIndent: 20,
                  ),
              
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );   }
    
      void animateToSlide(int index) => carouselController.animateToPage(index); }
```